# How important is a GPU for modeling?

Tags: modeling, gpu

I don't plan to be doing much cycles rendering, but I wanted to know if a GPU is still important if I'm doing high-poly modeling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will *assume* you are talking about an external GPU in this case, say a Nvidia GTX 660 etc..

Excerpt from the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html?#gpu-rendering)

> ...GPU rendering makes it possible to use your graphics card for
> **rendering**, instead of the CPU. This can speed up rendering, because
> modern GPUs are quite designed to do a lot of number crunching...

In short, **No**, you do not need an external GPU. Not to get too technical but except for [drawing and viewport stuff amongst some other things](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?257323-What-everybody-needs-to-know-about-Blender-Viewport-performance), much of Blender's core functionality relies very little on a *fully fledged GPU*.

For modeling in your case, **you are perfectly fine with just a decent CPU and an onboard graphics card that supports OpenGL** *(which in these modern times is pretty much every one of them)*.

*Having one would be nice though as this can greatly improve the viewport performance among other things but it is not a major requirement unless you are going to be doing very heavy or demanding production work.*

> **Graphics card note:** Blender runs on all OpenGL compliant cards,
> although there are some issues with cheap onboard cards (Intel, Via).
> We therefore can't officially support and guarantee that Blender works
> fine on those systems.

You can see the [system requirements for Blender here](http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/requirements/).

Comment: High-poly modeling is not a very clear term, but if that includes sculpting I would definitely recommend a good NVidia or AMD GPU with 1GB memory minimum. Even for moderately complex scenes it's best to avoid onboard graphics whenever possible.

Comment: I think this answer needs to be a bit more clear about the role that the GPU plays in rendering the viewport. Every point/line/poly that shows up in the viewport has to be rendered by the GPU. In fact, the principles are (by design) extremely similar to 3D gaming. Asking if you need a GPU for Blender is almost exactly like asking if you need a GPU to play computer games: it depends. Do you want to play Crysis or Tetris? Are you okay with playing Crysis at 2 fps on the lowest settings, or do you need to run max settings at 120 fps? It all depends.

Comment: @Matt I think I summarized it well enough _(it's good to have one but not necessarily needed)_ so feel free to add to it if you wish or roll your own answer :).

Comment: I take that back, I overlooked the link you provided to "What everybody needs to know about Blender Viewport performance." That should suffice ;-)

Answer (score -3):

On-board Graphic cards are not much powerful.Its just one simple fact,if you want fast renders you will need a good graphic card.
Rendering time also depends on material. Suppose if you use SSS, you "will" need a graphic card.

Comment: the question, while perhaps not explicit enough, suggests that the major use case will be high poly viewport editing, and not rendering which your answer concentrates on.

Comment: Not only that, but SSS is not yet available on the GPU.

Comment: Renders are only *capable* of using the GPU in cycles. The GPU will not affect renders in the slightest outside cycles.