# General system specs for large scenes in blender

Tags: performance

What are the system requirements for working with complex geometry in Blender? Things like RAM, GPU, CPU etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Hardware related questions are generally considered off-topic. Also your question is a bit vague. What would you call a 'large scene'?

Answer (score 3):

Blender's website has a page dedicated to this, it is now dated a few years but is still useful (was updated for 2.6).

http://archive.blender.org/features-gallery/requirements/index.html

If you are considering building a PC for 3D, anything from *Average* and up should suffice for fairly complex scenes.

> **Minimal specs for Hardware**
>
> - 32 bits, Dual Core CPU with at least 2 GHZ, and SSE2 support.
> - 2 GB RAM
> - 24 bits 1280x768 display
> - Mouse or trackpad
> - OpenGL Graphics Card with 256 MB RAM
>
> **Average specs for Hardware**
>
> - 64 bits, Quad Core CPU
> - 8 GB RAM
> - Full HD Display with 24 bit color
> - Mouse or trackpad
> - OpenGL Graphics Card with 1 GB RAM
>
> **Production specs for Hardware**
>
> - 64 bits, Dual 8 Core CPU
> - 16 GB RAM
> - Two times Full HD Display with 24 bit color
> - Mouse + tablet
> - Dual OpenGL Graphics Cards, quality brand with 3 GB RAM

Also related: [What are the best graphics cards for cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/best-video-cards-for-cycles) and [How important is a GPU for modeling?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/722/how-important-is-a-gpu-if-im-not-doing-cycles-rendering/723#723)